# How does linux kernel creates sysfs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, sysfs

I have started looking at linux kernel code for my OS course. In that I'm interested in sys file system (sysfs). I'm interested in finding out when and how sysfs gets created? Which files in linux kernel code generate this file system?

I have setup linux kernel on my system and have started debugging through the code.

I have referred to this document to understand sysfs file system :
[sysfs] : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt

But this document explains only about directory structure, creation of directories and reading/writing attributes. I'm more interested in how kernel creates these directories during booting . 
I understood that following method is responsible for directory creation in sysfs.

```
   int sysfs_create_file(struct kobject *kobj, struct attribute *attr);
```

This function accepts kboject structure, attributes and using these it creates directory in sysfs.

I understood that at the time of boot, kernel detects the memory and creates the directories  under sys/devices/system/memory. I'm planning to change this directory structure as part of my homework. So, could you please point me to files and methods which are responsible for creation of this specific memory directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use that kind of functions directly. You should also avoid the use of `kobject` (unless you are touching the kernel core).

Usually, sysfs attribute are associated to the `device` structure. So, when you register a device the sysfs attribute are created.

Take a look at the `device` structure in [device.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/device.h) line 689. At the end of the structure you will find the following field

```
const struct attribute_group **groups;
```

You have to create your own attribute, insert them in an attribute group and assigns your groups to your device before invoking `device_register()`

If you follow the `device_register()` function, you will see what it does to create the associated sysfs attribute

Answer (score 4):

The code for sysfs resides in `fs/sysfs/` . Kernel will create a sysfs in `sysfs_init` , and mount it by function `sysfs_mount` .

You may find the paper [*The sysfs Filesystem*](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/mochel/doc/papers/ols-2005/mochel.pdf) by Patrick Mochel useful, as it introduces **how sysfs works** and **code organization** of sysfs in the kernel.